# pyspark streaming fill all millisecond

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming-kafka

I'm new a pyspark streaming i have a data stream from kafka that i want to fill every 0.1 seconds the timestamp from kafka is irregular I'm trying to fill all timestamp that are not there with the previous number. and i want to know how to deal with the batch.

**input kafka Stream:**

| type | number | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| car | 7777 | '2023-10-28 14:22:41.9' |
| car | 8888 | '2023-10-28 14:22:42.5' |
| car | 1111 | '2023-10-28 14:22:42.7' |
| motor | 2222 | '2023-10-28 14:22:41.2' |
| motor | 6666 | '2023-10-28 14:22:41.5' |

```
# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("KafkaStream").getOrCreate()


# Read data from Kafka as a streaming DataFrame
df = spark \
      .readStream \
      .format("kafka") \
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "broker:29092") \
      .option("subscribe", "now") \
      .option("minOffsetsPerTrigger", 10) \
      .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 15) \
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
      .load()

schema = StructType([
    StructField("type", StringType(), True),
        StructField("number", LongType(), True),
        StructField("timestamp", StringType(), True)
])

output = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
    .select(from_json(col("value"), schema).alias("data")) \
    .select("data.*")


window_spec = Window.partitionBy("type").orderBy("type", "timestamp")

df = output.withColumn(
    "next_timestamp", to_timestamp(lead(col("timestamp")).over(window_spec))
)

result_df = df.withColumn(
    "timestamp",
    expr(
        "explode(sequence(to_timestamp(timestamp), nvl(next_timestamp, to_timestamp(timestamp)), interval 100 milliseconds))"
    ),
).withColumn(
    "to_drop",
    when((col("timestamp") == col("next_timestamp")), True).otherwise(False)
)
x = result_df.filter(col('to_drop') == False).drop("next_timestamp", "to_drop")

# Create a streaming query to process the data and fill missing values
query = x\
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

**output batch in the console:**

| type | number | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| car | 7777 | '2023-10-28 14:22:41.9' |
| car | 7777 | '2023-10-28 14:22:42.0' |
| car | 7777 | '2023-10-28 14:22:42.1' |
| car | 7777 | '2023-10-28 14:22:42.2' |
| car | 7777 | '2023-10-28 14:22:42.3' |
| car | 7777 | '2023-10-28 14:22:42.4' |
| car | 8888 | '2023-10-28 14:22:42.5' |
| car | 8888 | '2023-10-28 14:22:42.6' |
| car | 1111 | '2023-10-28 14:22:42.7' |
| motor | 2222 | '2023-10-28 14:22:41.2' |
| motor | 2222 | '2023-10-28 14:22:41.3' |
| motor | 2222 | '2023-10-28 14:22:41.4' |
| motor | 6666 | '2023-10-28 14:22:41.5' |

Comment: For how long do you want to fill? You have to set a limit.

Comment: @boyangeor i want to fill from first car timestamp( '2023-10-28 14:22:41.9' ) until latest car timestamp  where the number have changes in my example until ( '2023-10-28 14:22:42.4' ) and the same think for the rest of the values in column "Type". can you  please show me what have i done wrong because i am new at Spark streaming.